# Google Music app split actionbar

Tags: android, split, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

The new Google Music app looks like it is using the new action bar API's with the split action bar items at the bottom. The cool thing is that it also works on my Nexus S Gingerbread phone, which doesn't have the new ICS API's. So, my question is of course how can I achieve that?

[image: Google Music app]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Music app's action bar is a custom implementation, not a backport.

Comment: and I assume that's true for the Android Market app as well?

Comment: Market uses a hybrid - a custom implementation for devices < Android 3.0 and the system action bar for >= 3.0. Selectively using a custom layout for the bar on older platform versions is quite simple when it does not need to be fully generalized. :)

Answer (score 2):

They are probably using some in-house / private action bar lib backported from ics.

Search for Sherlock Action bar lib. The new version 4.0 which will be out soon will allow you to use ics action bar api on older android versions.

Comment: yes, I knew about ActionBar Sherlock and it's awesome btw, but I am waiting for 4.0 so I can use the split action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own view at the bottom -- Linear Layout and add ImageButtons to this layout.

Comment: yes, I know that's possible. I was just wondering if it's possible using the action bar on pre ICS devices.

Comment: Unfortunately not using the standard sdk apis. You can use it on Android 3.0 devices but split action bar is not available

Comment: so how did they make this Music app available on Gingerbread devices? custom ?